# Wordpress Multisite URLs and Multiple Updates

Tags: multisite, updates

Is it possible to run a WordPress multisite using different domain urls? As opposed to just subdomains?

I basically have two (and soon to be three) personal sites and they all run the same theme and plugins, albeit under different domains / web addresses. The main reason I would like to do this is to make updating themes and plugins less time consuming, as opposed to doing it to save a few pounds a month on hosting costs.

Is it possible to have a multisite environment so I can update the themes and plugins in one go (I would test updates on a localhost site first that is running the theme / plugins set-up question etc).

Any help / ideas greatly appreciated.

Emily.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Domain-based) of the Codex refers suggests the plugin [WPMU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).

> Additionally, you can map domains like example1.com, example2.com, etc, however a plugin is suggested (like [WPMU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)). You can make the changes directly in the network settings, but it's considered advanced administration.